# I cannot get my logon to execute

Tags: php, mysql, apache, database-connection, server

I have a logon form which reads as

```
<h1>Log In</h1>
<div style="width: 80%;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto">
<form action="checklogin.php" method="POST">
   <p>
   User ID:<br />
   <input type="text" name="username"><br />
   Password:<br />
   <input type="password" name="pass" ><br />
   <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Login">
```

This then goes to validate as follows

```
// Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 

mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE username='$username' and pass= SHA1('$pass');

//$result=mysql_query($sql);

$result=mysql_query($sql, $connect) or die(" Could not execute query");
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

I know that the contact with the server is correct as I've tested that bit for errors, but whatever I try I can't get past the statement

> **"Could not execute query"**

The table headings are `username` and `pass` and the password is encrypted on the server.

I'm a newbie and cannot understand the PHP manual as far as this little lot goes.

The host is `1and1` and they use an `Apache server`

Comment: Change your `die` to `die(mysql_error())` to see the real error.

Comment: `where is $sql defined?`

Comment: I've defined the $sql = "SELECT -- etc and changed die to your recommedation and got a blank page. Dos that mean there's nothing wrong with the mysql after all?

Comment: add these two lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` top of your php code, after `<?php` and now tell me what error do you see after running your php code?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I've got a bit further now, plus I'd done something really silly. I've got rid of the SHA1 bit for now and am testing un-encrypted passwords so I can see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youve not put your query in a string

youve not passed in your values properly

youve not closed your `<form>` tag in the HTML

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 

mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE username='$username' and pass= SHA1('$pass')";

$result=mysql_query($sql, $connect) or die(" Could not execute query");

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

you should also be using mysqli, not mysql as its deprecated.

Comment: The form tag is closed, I forgot to copy it - sorry. I've fixed the missing $sql = "SELECT etc and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm only getting the message ERROR: now, but no list of errors

Comment: put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of the file (inside the php tag) and see if that gives you any more info

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Now I know what to address. It's given me a few warnings and a notice. I'll work through them now and hopefully it'll work. As a newbie it's not easy to know all the wrinkles. I'm going to keep this string to help with any more problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 

mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
//EDIT 
$sql = SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE username='$username' and pass= SHA1('$pass');

//$result=mysql_query($sql);

$result=mysql_query($sql, $connect);
if(!$result) {
    die('ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
}
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Oh dear, that just gives me a page with ERROR: on it and nothing else.  Once I get this little lot going properly I will start testing mysqli but I really need this to run first. Should I ditch the "SHA1" and change the password in the table to plain text. Could it be something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the $sql variable is never actually set to anything, which could be causing your problem.  Also, you are using the mysql extension which is deprecated and replaced with the mysqli extension.  An example of connecting with msyqli (it's a pretty similar extension):

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp